# How to check the 'id' values in the controller?

Tags: codeigniter

my javascript code values that will print the data from ajax response

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getval(get) {

        var id =  get.value;
        // alert(id);

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url :"http://localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/admin/ajax",
            data :{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                $('#sub_category').html(data);
                //window.location = "<?php echo site_url('admin/examdetails/form'); ?>"
            }
        });  
    }
</script>
```

Controller Function: that will handle ajax request

```
function ajax() 
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert(id);";
    echo "</script>";

    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $query = $this->admin_model->get_sub_details($id);

    echo  '<select name="sub_category" id="sub_category">';

    foreach($query->result_array as $row)
    {                
        $name = $row['name']; 
        $id   = $row['id'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'$name'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: why are you writing html, javascript in controller?

Comment: Its not in controller ,its is written in view Page #Lokesh

Comment: please post your controller and view code properly so we can help you!!

Comment: thought it can be done, loading another instance of the model in the view page is unnecessary overhead. Also, please post ALL of your code related to what you're doing.

Comment: your jquery must have `$(function(){ //your all jquery code here });`

Comment: try to echo at the end of the `function ajax()` .. the moment you `echo` it will send the response to the view.. and other lines will not be executed.. so make changes.. and try it again..